# Ongoing notification that gets updated every instance

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

In my application, I want to implement an always updating ongoing notification, like an alarm clock running in the notification center.

I tried to make a service that runs every minute to update the time in the notification center, but sadly I found it not efficient enough as it drains the battery a lot!

What's the most efficient solution to make an always updating notification that doesn't drain the battery?
Thank you!

Codes:

Service:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    MyClass MyClass;
    public PrayerTimeAlarmService() {
        super("PrayerTimeAlarmService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(MyClass == null){
            MyClass = new NextSalah(this);
        }
        MyClass.updatenotification();
    }

}
```

The Update Void:

```
public updatenotification(){
        title = GetTitle();/*the title is dynamically generated based on complex codes*/
        timediff = GetTimeDiff(title);/*joda time period and stuff calculations*/
        NB.setContentTitle(title);
        NB.setContentText(timedif);
        NB.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification not = NB.build();
        not.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(071527/*Just a random integer*/ , not);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by always updating? every second?

Comment: @Nima i need it every minute i think i have already mentioned that in the question

Comment: 2 weeks no reply can anyone help me please :(